# Pass EXEC statement to APPLY as a parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a need to grab data from multiple databases which has tables with the same schema. For this I created synonyms for this tables in the one of the databases. The number of databases will grow with time. So, the procedure, which will grab the data should be flexible. I wrote the following code snippet to resolve the problem:

```
WHILE @i < @count
BEGIN
    SELECT @synonymName = [Name]
    FROM Synonyms
    WHERE [ID] = @i
        SELECT @sql = 'SELECT TOP (1) * 
                FROM [dbo].[synonym' + @synonymName + '] as syn
                WHERE [syn].[Id] = tr.[Id]
                ORDER BY [syn].[System.ChangedDate] DESC'

        INSERT INTO @tmp
        SELECT  col1, col2
        FROM
        (
            SELECT * FROM TableThatHasRelatedDataFromAllTheSynonyms
            WHERE [Date] > @dateFrom 
        ) AS tr         
        OUTER APPLY (EXEC(@sql)) result 

    SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

I also appreciate for any ideas on how to simplify the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is quite simple. Just to put all the query to the string and exec it. Unfortunately it works 3 times slower than just copy/past the code for all the synonyms.

```
WHILE @i < @count
BEGIN
    SELECT @synonymName = [Name]
    FROM Synonyms
    WHERE [ID] = @i
        SELECT @sql = 'SELECT  col1, col2
        FROM
        (
            SELECT * FROM TableThatHasRelatedDataFromAllTheSynonyms
            WHERE [Date] > ''' + @dateFrom + '''
        ) AS tr         
        OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) * 
                FROM [dbo].[synonym' + @synonymName + '] as syn
                WHERE [syn].[Id] = tr.[Id]
                ORDER BY [syn].[System.ChangedDate] DESC) result'

        INSERT INTO @tmp
        EXEC(@sql)

    SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's better to import data from all tables into one table (maybe with additional column for source table name) and use it. Importing can be performed through SP or SSIS package.

Regarding initial question - you can achieve it through TVF wrapper for exec statement (with exec .. into inside it).

**UPD:** As noticed in the comments exec doesn't work inside TVF. So, if you really don't want to change DB structure and you need to use a lot of tables I suggest to:

1. OR select all data from synonym*** table into variables (as I see you select only one row) and use them
2. OR prepare dynamic SQL for complete statement (with insert, etc.) and use temporary table instead of table variable here.

Comment: I'll try it, tomorrow, hope it will help me. And can you give more details about "SP or SSIS" actually I didn't get what you meant. And unfortunately I couldn't glue all the tables into one because they are big enough. (SELECT * FROM Table1) - query takes from 30 up to 60 seconds on the server with Intel Xeon processor and 12 Gb RAM, and I had multiple tables. Query with "OUTER APPLY" takes less than 2-3 seconds

Comment: SP - stored procedure. 
SSIS - SQL Server Integration Services. 
TVF - Table Valued Function.

Comment: I faced with another problem, when tried to extract the query into the TVF:  Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'EXECUTE STRING' within a function.